# Invalid name "Con"

Tags: operating-system, naming, invalidation

I tried **Con** as name of a folder, but the system will not accept it. Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: See following for list of invalid filenames: https://help.nomadesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201719541--Filename-contains-invalid-characters-notification#:~:text=The%20following%20file%20names%20are,txt%20does%20not%20work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reserved and specified in IO.SYS and date back from the early MS Dos days. Here is a brief list:

CLOCK$ - System clock

CON - Console; a combination of keyboard and screen to handle input and output

AUX or COM1 - First serial communicationport

COMn - Second, Third, ... communicationport

LPT1 or PRN - First parallel port

NUL - Dummy port, or the "null device" which we all know under Linux as /dev/null.